# How does the Spring Force vs. Displacement graph of a deformed spring look like?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring

I've never seen a deformed spring in my life, so I don't really know how it would behave. But as we know, via Hooke's Law, that there's a positive relationship between the force of a spring with an attached mass and the distance the spring is displaced from an equilibrium as the mass increases.

Let's assume now that I'm working a spring factory and I'm checking the quality of the springs manufactured by hooking them onto masses and determining their spring constants by graphing them. How would the graph of a deformed spring look like?

Comment: -1. No research effort.

Answer (score 1):

Take a helical spring and compress it and then extend it. Measure the force as a function of displacement and you are looking at a curve that looks like this:

[image: frc1]

The linear range near the free length is the working range. On either end of the length spectrum the stiffness increases by orders of magnitude.